# Using Java code in Leiningen project

Tags: java, clojure, leiningen

My Leiningen project requires a few external Java classes that I am trying to access from Clojure.

At first I tried putting the class files in my_project/resources/ since this directory is on the classpath which is confirmed by running

```
lein classpath
```

However, I couldn't access even a simple toy Java class from Clojure which resides in said directory. To keep things as simple as possible, my toy class does not have a package declaration.

My second approach involved adding a :java-source-path key to my project.clj, but I was again struck by failure (same behaviour as above, I can't access the class from a Clojure REPL).

Where am I going wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

Couple of things that could be wrong:

Are you using .class files or .java files? java-source-path is for *sources*, that is, .java files. And .java files need to be compiled before they can be loaded.

Also, java classes need to be either imported or qualified with their full package name in clojure code.

If possible and your java code isn't directly tied to the clojure stuff, it's easiest to just have your java files compiled and bundled in a jar that you can add to the dependencies of your leiningen project.

Comment: Both the .class and .java files reside both in resources/ and the java sources directory (java/ in my case). Anyway, since resources/ *is* in fact on the classpath I would expect the Java classes to be available easily from Clojure (my Java classes do not have any package declaration, therefore I expect them to be available without importing anything).

Comment: I would not count on classes without packages to just be available everywhere automatically, but I don't know the specifics of the java class loader or compiler. Clojure itself requires explicit imports for anything outside of java.lang (even clojure.lang classes aren't imported automatically). If no better suggestions turn up, I would try and set up packages for the classes (with the corresponding directories for the java files and import statements in the clojure code)

Comment: Outside of the time limit for edits: if your classes don't have packages, I guess a plain `(import 'YourClass)` in the clojure code should work, though using at least 2 levels of packages is recommended in clojure, for technical reasons I can't really remember right now.

Answer (score 0):

After putting the java source in the path, did you run lein compile?

Comment: Yes, and it compiled correctly. However, Joost solved my problem (which was a missing import).

Answer (score 0):

In your .project file for your project specify the :java-source-paths as ["java"] and not "java"<sup>1</sup> if the "java" directory is where you put the java source files in your project's directory.

Running 'lein run' should auto compile java sources before actually running if you've specified the :java-source-paths  and :main right in your .project file.

Source: https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/master/doc/MIXED_PROJECTS.md

1. I made this mistake and kept wondering what I was doing wrong. The Chas Emerick Clojure programming book in the relational database chapter that talks about hibernate needs to be updated a bit.

Answer (score 0):

In your project.clj do you have a keyword for your resource paths? You said you have the java-source-paths keyword, but those are used for .java files that need to be compiled when your project is built / ran. In your project.clj file add this

```
:resource-paths ["relative/path/to/your/classes/folder" "relative/path/to/other/classes"]
```

This will allow your project to reference your various classes with an import statement in your namespace declaration.

```
(ns my.project.name-space
  (:require [clojure.core.async :as async])
  (:import MySuperAwesomeClass))
```